# Direct sum of Null space and its complement

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

My textbook has this problem.

> Suppose $T:V\rightarrow F$. Suppose $u\in V$ is not in null($T$). Prove that $$V=Null(T) \bigoplus \{au: a\in F\}$$

Now, if the set $\{au: a\in F\}$ is a subspace of $V$, I can prove it using definition of direct sum, as below. But I think $\{au: a\in F\}$ is not a subspace of V. Can someone point out where I am wrong in my argument/understanding?

**Proof (assuming the set $\{au: a\in F\}$ is a subspace of $V$):**

Definition of direct sum : If $U,W$ are subspaces of $V$, and $U+W=V, U\cap W=\{0\}$, then $U\bigoplus W=V$.

So, I can prove Null$(T)\cap \{au: a\in F\}=\{0\}$, using the fact $T(au)=0\Rightarrow a=0.$, and since $\{au: a\in F\}$ is the union of $\{0\}$ and $u\notin Null(T), V=Null(T)+{au: a\in F\}$.

**Why I think $\{au: a\in F\}$ is NOT a subspace of $V$:**

Counter example:

Let $V$ is $R^3$. $T$ is a linear map from $R^3$ to $R$, $T:(x,y,z)\rightarrow x$ i.e. $T$ maps $3-D$ space to x-axis. Here null space of $T$ is the $y-z$ plane, $x=0$. $\{au: a\in F\}$ is the set $x\neq 0$. Now consider two elements $(6x + y)$ and $(-6x + y)$, $x,y \neq 0$. $(6x + y),(-6x + y)\in \{au: a\in F\}$, but $(6x + y)+(-6x + y)=2y \notin \{au: a\in F\}$,  $$(6x + y)+(-6x + y)=2y\in Null(T)$.

So   $\{au: a\in F\}$ is not a subspace. Now, since the definition of direct sum specifies that the elements should be subspaces, then I can't say $V=Null(T) \bigoplus \{au: a\in F\}$

Comment: $\{au\,:\,a\in F\}$ is a subspace of $V$; it is the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $u$. In your last  "counterexample" it is not clear what you're taking as $u$. THe null space of $T$ is $\{(0,y,z)\in \Bbb{R}^3\,:\, y,z\in \Bbb{R}\}$. You have to take $u$ to be a vector in $\Bbb{R}^3$ not belonging to the null space. So for example, $u= (1,1,0)$. Then, $\{au\,:\, a\in \Bbb{R}\}$ is indeed a subspace.

Comment: ok. So, this claim is valid for a single fixed u not in null space of T. I was thinking it is claimed to be valid for all u not in null space of T, and all of them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fix one vector $u$ not in the kernel of $T$ and consider $\{au:a \in F\}$. In your example you can take $(1,0,0)$ for $u$. In that case  $\{au:a \in F\}=\{(a,0,0): a \in F\}$ which is a subspace.